# Clicking link_to root_url causes CSS to disappear with jquerymobile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

The CSS for my site works fine on desktop browsers and mobile browsers, but when I click the link to return back to the main page "root_path", some of my CSS stylings disappear.

```
#routes.rb
 resources :welcomes
 root :to => "welcomes#index"


#_header.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Welcome!', root_url %>

#application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" if mobile_device? %>
```

If I view it using the url `http://192.168.1.4:3000` it looks great. When I click the 'welcome' link in the in the header I lose CSS styling. I think it's because the url becomes `http://192.168.1.4:3000/#/`. Why is it not just `/`?  I've tried `root_path`, `root_url`, `welcomes_path`, etc all with the same result.

Comment: The `root` route for `routes.rb` was already in the question. I added the `resources` declaration. The file is very vanilla.

Comment: How is your css linked?  Do you lose all the styles for one particular file or only a few?

Comment: I only lose a few styles. Namely background color, body color, and font stylings. The header and footer stylings stay.

Comment: I think I can help if you publish your app somewhere. This is an interesting case. Leave a comment with a link to your app here and let me try my best ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the bug report [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1284), I believe this is a bug in jquerymobile.

**Update**
Indeed JQuery mobile Beta 3 resolved the issue.